# Possible neck brace worn by Melissa McCarthy in The Boss

Tags: character, costume, the-boss

I was watching a trailer for Melissa McCathy's latest film *The Boss* when I noticed nearly in every scene she is wearing a high of topped dress/outfit. Check out the images below.

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know if she is suffering from neck problems or if it is just for her character.

Comment: A turtleneck is one thing...in The Boss Melissa McCarthy basically wore material to the base of her chin...odd, strange looking. Like watching someone wearing their clothes inside out without realizing it.

Comment: @Tracy Yeah...that's the look that she was going for with this character.  Melissa McCarthy wanted something absurd, yet still classy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wondered the exact same thing after I saw this movie.  I knew that Melissa McCarthy went through a drastic weight loss recently and I thought that she may have had extra skin removed and she was just hiding that with those high neck scarves and turtlenecks.

This is not the case.  Melissa McCarthy envisioned this character and her wardrobe long ago and wardrobe designer Wendy Chuck helped her realize her vision with that character.  From a [People magazine interview](http://people.com/style/melissa-mccarthy-i-am-a-size-14-and-i-love-designing-clothes-for-women-of-all-sizes/):

> Her new experience in the fashion world also inspired the star to get
>   behind-the-scenes in the wardrobe apartment while filming The Boss.
>
> While character Michelle isn’t quite as in-tune with the ‘less is
>   more’ approach to style, McCarthy says it was “a blast” to go with
>   “the more absurd” looks.
>
> She adds of the process, “once we knew who she was, which I’ve known
>   for a long time, it’s like, you couldn’t fool Michelle. She requires a
>   certain amount of pomp and circumstance. Nobody wanted to see Michelle
>   in dockers and a t-shirt.

This wardrobe does not have an out of universe explanation.  It is simply Melissa McCarthy's vision for the character.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It's good to know someone else was thinking the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything specific, nor have I heard of anything specific, but I can show you these clips:

April 3, 2016

April 4, 2016

April 7, 2016

In none of these interviews is she wearing any sort of neck brace.  So, my best guess is that it was for her character.

Comment: The movie was shot a year before that, though (filming began on March 12, 2015).

Comment: Here's an interview from June 2015.  She's got good neck movement.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcmcVK0q4SE